# How to calculate confidence score from dependency parse tree?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

Is there any way to get confidence score or any score from dependency parse tree of a sentence using ntlk or something else?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard task, I am not aware of any tool doing it, but if you probably post something on the corpora mailing list, or language technology section of reddit you will get better replies. But if was a research question, I would suggest training a PCFG on a penntreebank dataset and then using it to compute the probabilities of parse trees assigned to sentences. You can grab [Mark Johnson's](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~mjohnson/Software.htm) implementation. Search for this line:

> cky.tbz contains a very fast C implementation of a CKY PCFG parser,
>   together with programs for extracting PCFGs from treebanks, etc. This
>   was used in my 1999 CL article. (last updated 6th March, 2006)

CYK (viterbi) is a dynamic programming algorithm. PCFG stands for probabilistic CFG, which you typically train using penntreebank dataset. The summation over the probabilities of all possible parse trees for a sentence can be interpreted as how grammatically correct the sentence is. Sorry if this wasn't the actual answer, but this is a working answer and I can tell you more details if you decided to do it :).